# Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger for the query I ran

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger which updates my 'ratio' column automatically within the same table. I need to sort by date(month and year) for the specific items get the sum for the items at that date then divide by the item values.

This is the query I tried:

```
create trigger ratio
before update
ON Table1
for each row
(select Month,Year,sum(item_value) as sum_item
    from Table1
    where item_name like ('BUC%')
    group by Month,Year) x
on Table1.Month = x.Month and Table1.Year = x.Year and Table1.item_name like ('BUC%')
set Table1.Ratio = Table1.item_value/x.sum_item;
```

but I get the error `Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger` which I kind of understand. I'm very new to mysql by the way.

If I can't do what I want this way is there another way or method to get it done?

Comment: You need an `UPDATE` query, not a `SELECT` query.

Comment: But a trigger isn't allowed to update the same table it's triggering on.

Comment: You can only update the ratio column for the row being updated through  `NEW.column_name = ...` construct.

Comment: I told you the same thing in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365024/how-do-i-divide-two-cells-after-selectively-adding-in-mysql

Comment: @Barmar but you can perform simple trigger updates with `set new.column_name = new.col_name + 2` in the same table and it works. Is there a way at all to do what I want or is it simply not possible? can I break it into sub queries or something?

Comment: Yes, you can change the value in the row being updated. But it looks lik you're trying to update all rows with the same item.

Comment: @Barmar not with the same item but divide through the same value returned by the sum function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the total value for the same product and month, and use that to calculate the ratio for the updated row.

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger ratio
before update
ON Table1
for each row
IF item_name LIKE 'BUC%'
THEN
    SET NEW.ratio = NEW.item_value/(
        SELECT SUM(item_value) 
        FROM Table1 
        WHERE item_name = NEW.item_name AND month = NEW.month AND year = NEW.year
    );
END IF$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it looks really close to the answer I want but at the moment it returns a syntax error on the last line.

Comment: I forgot `END IF;`

Comment: There is still a syntax error. Now it's on the final two lines. `missing ';'`

Comment: Needed to end the procedure with the defined delimiter.